# Start, end and stopping condition of Binary Search code

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, binary-search

I hope everyone is doing well.

I know there are a lot of questions whose title is very much similar to my question but I have a doubt regarding start and end values :-

- If I use stopping condition as `start<=end` then, whether start=0 ,end=n/n-1|start=-1,end=n-1/n|start=-2 to end=n-2| start=-3 to end=n-3 **the output is same in all these cases for the below code

  **while(l<=r)
  {
  int mid=(l+r)/2;**

  ```
       if(arr[mid]==k)
           return mid;
       else if(k>arr[mid])
           l=mid+1;
       else
           r=mid-1;
   }
  ```
- From start=-4 to end=-4 the result is wrong.
- I've read the other questions and learned the fact that changing the stopping condition changes the range of start and end (inclusive/ exclusive ) but,
- Why is binary search working for start=0/-1/-2/-3 to end=n/n+1/n+2/n+3? I mean apart from starting mid=(n-2+2)/2<=> n/2, there may be a condition when the target element appears at arr[0].

Thanks for spending your precious time in solving my query.

I hope I've written clearly.

Comment: Have you tried a case with `start, end` as `-3, n-3` and the target element at `n-1`?

Answer (score 1):

> If I use stopping condition as start<=end then, whether start=0 ,end=n/n-1|start=-1,end=n-1/n|start=-2 to end=n-2| start=-3 to end=n-3 the output is same in all these cases for the below code.

This is not true. `start` and `end` must start at precisely the first and last index of the array, or there will be cases where the algorithm you provided fails. So assuming zero-based array indexing, `start = 0, end = n - 1` is the only correct initialisation for this algorithm.

Here are counter examples for some alternatives:

- `start = 0, end = n`: if `k` is a value that is greater than the greatest value in `arr`, then eventually `mid` will become equal to `n` and `arr[mid]` will be an invalid reference. Depending on the language this may trigger an exception.
- `start = -1, end = n - 1`: if `k` is a value that is less than the least value in `arr`, then eventually `mid` will become equal to -1 and `arr[mid]` will be an invalid reference.
- `start = -2, end = n - 2`. if `k == arr[0]` and `n == 3`, the element will not be found, as `mid` will get the value -1.
- `start = -2, end = n + 2`. if `k == arr[0]` and `n == 3`, the element will not be found, as `mid` will get the value 1 and in the next iteration it will be -1, so skipping for ever the index 0.
- ...etc